# Taking a screenshot of a whole scrollable view in Android

Tags: android, screenshot

I am looking for an Android application that can capture a single element of a long list of options, or a complete scrollable list in one shot, i.e. not cropping like this:

[image]

just like [Capture View](http://www.addictivetips.com/ios/capture-screenshots-of-scrollable-ios-screens-individual-ui-elements/) or [Stitch It!](https://itunes.apple.com/US/app/id554594252?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4) for iPhone.

If possible, free and compatible with Samsung Galaxy S3 + Android 4.1.2.

The result should be like (of course without the blur):

[image]

Comment: Worst case you can always take multiple shots and glue them together with a photo editor on your phone... But I'm interested in your question, +1

Comment: @Johnride yeah... That is a worst case :)