# Current Internet speed in status bar for Android

Tags: gratis, android, internet

I am looking for a free Android application that can display the current Internet speed (upstream and downstream) in the status bar, just like the non-free application [Internet Speed Meter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.internet.speed.meter&hl=en) can do:

[image]

It should support 4G and Wi-Fi connections.

Comment: Does your device have ROOT access ?!

Comment: @WingedPanther Not yet, but I am open to suggestions that require it.

Comment: what about this > [Net Speed Meter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ckideas.networkmeter&hl=en),If you have root access then there are many way to do it

Comment: @WingedPanther Thanks that's almost perfect: I just wish there was a way put the meter in the status bar. But otherwise it has some great option! Can you please add it as an answer?

Comment: Root your device and explore lots of hidden feature on your device btw what's your device model ?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900A with Android 4.4.2. I just got it: my previous phone was a Samsung I9300 Galaxy S III with a rooted Android 4.1.2. The main missing features with unrooted Android for me are no screencast and no VNC server (and no way to remove the crapware installed by default by Samsung and AT&T -> I don't want to go to CyanogenMod though).

Comment: You can manually remove bloatwares(crapware) from your Rooted device easily or for unrooted device just disable not using  bloatwares

Comment: @WingedPanther Good catch :) actually in this case I had to cut a bit the first screenshot. Ideally I am looking for a solution for [taking a screenshot of a whole scrollable view in Android](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7546/903).

Comment: can I answer photojoiner in [taking a screenshot of a whole scrollable view in Android](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7546/taking-a-screenshot-of-a-whole-scrollable-view-in-android)

Comment: @WingedPanther With photojoiner one would still have to take several screenshots, then upload them to photo joiner, right? Also does photojoiner have some clever merging (viz. if two screenshots overlap photojoiner remove the overlap)?

Comment: @WingedPanther So far I have just been luring around  http://forum.xda-developers.com/ :) definitely a great resource!

Comment: *Yes*, Its a web application

Comment: @WingedPanther Some crapware seems to be only nukable with root, e.g. [How can I prevent the AT&T update software from using my 4G connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/89943/12202), but yes indeed most of it can be removed without it.

Comment: @WingedPanther Hmmm I fear photojoiner won't do a good job for  taking a screenshot of a whole scrollable view: it seems to just merge pictures but e.g. if I had used it to show Net Speed Meter's parameters the result would have been pretty much the same as the image I added in your answer :/ I am looking for something smooth like http://i.stack.imgur.com/UPwtV.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Net Speed Meter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ckideas.networkmeter&hl=en)

**Features**

- No matter what App run in the foreground, you can alway know the network throughput.
- Display the network throughput with chart.
- Tap and slip the chart to anywhere you want!
- The chart can auto hide after there is no network traffic for a while.
- Custom your view ! You can disable chart, let it show only numeric.
- Monitor network type support: 3G, wifi, Bluetooth.
- Free

All settings:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have a good  one:

### Gravity Box

It requires a rooted phone with Xposed framework installed but it integrates pretty well with the notification bar.

[image: Img]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Or can also mod the signal icon as well as the battery icon.